# Numpy memmap still using RAM instead of disk while doing vector operation

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management, numpy-memmap

I initialize two operands and one result:

```
a = np.memmap('a.mem', mode='w+', dtype=np.int64, shape=(2*1024*1024*1024))
b = np.memmap('b.mem', mode='w+', dtype=np.int64, shape=(2*1024*1024*1024))
result = np.memmap('result.mem', mode='w+', dtype=np.int64, shape=(2*1024*1024*1024))
```

At idle state like that, the System RAM reported by Google Colab still `1.0/12.7 GB` which is good there is no RAM activities yet. But, doing this vector operation such as vector substraction, the reported system ram increased to the almost maximum peak which is `11.2/12.7 GB` that eventually the runtime kernel is crashed:

```
result[:] = a[:] - b[:] # This still consume memory
result.flush()
```

I have read `np.memmap` docs many times, it was asserted that the purpose of `memmap` is supposed to reduce memory consumption, but why I still got `Out Of Memory` error?

I suspect, the vector subtraction must be buffered into small chunk such as for every `512MB` buffer memory. But I have no idea what the syntax is:
Perhaps what I mean is something like this:

```
BUFF_SIZE = 512 * 1024 * 1024
for i in range(0, result.size, BUFF_SIZE):
  result[i:i+BUFF_SIZE] = a[i:i+BUFF_SIZE] - b[i:i+BUFF_SIZE]
  result.flush()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result[:] = a[:] - b[:]` doesn't mean "write the subtraction results directly into `result`". It means "write the subtraction results into a new array, then copy the contents of that array into `result`". You're attempting to create a 16 GiB temporary array in the middle.

To write the output directly into `result`, you can use the `out` parameter of the `numpy.subtract` ufunc:

```
numpy.subtract(a, b, out=c)
```

Comment: If I want to perform another operation such as `np.zeros`, `np.ones` or even copying an `memmap` array to the another destination `memmap`. `out` parameter is not available, I'm speaking generally.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira: `c[:] = 0`, `c[:] = 1`, and `c[:] = whatever_input_source`, respectively. There's no fully general way to avoid temporary arrays, though. You'll have to figure things out case by case.